# Override JQuery Selector to support Dollar Sign ($) in element id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am trying to write a JQuery plugin to support $ in element id, my code is:

DollarSignPlugin.js:

```
function escapeJQueryElementName(elementName) {
    elementName = elementName.replace(/\\\$/g, "$");

    return elementName.replace(/\$/g, "\\$");
}

var jQueryInit = $.fn.init;

$.fn.init = function(arg1, arg2, rootjQuery){
    arg2 = arg2 || window.document;
    if (arg1 && arg1.replace) {
        var newArg1 = escapeJQueryElementName(arg1);
        return new jQueryInit(newArg1, arg2, rootjQuery);
    }

    return new jQueryInit(arg1, arg2, rootjQuery);
};
```

It is working great, but i faced one issue with current line:

```
var $anyselector = $("#");
```

JQuery throw error "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #".

This line is from bootstrap when clicking on any tab with href="#".

This error doesn't appear when removing my plugin, also if i copy paste the replace function to directly the jquery file it works fine.

So is there a better way to override the selector or i have some issue with my code, please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you **don't** do this (but if you want to, keep reading, I do have a fix below), because:

1. It means you're using invalid selectors in your code, which is a maintenance issue — at some point, someone doing maintenance won't understand what's going on, or you'll hit an edge condition, etc.
2. Your current implementation will mess up things like

   ```
   $("<div>$12</div>").appendTo(document.body);
   ```

   (by putting a backslash in front of the dollar sign). Who knows what else it's messing up?

Instead, I'd just have a simple:

```
function $gid(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!e) {
        return $();
    }
    if (e.id === id) {
        return $(e);
    }
    // Fallback processing for old IE that matches name attributes
    return $('[id="' + id.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"]').filter(function() {
        return this.id === id;
    }).first();
}
```

Example:

```js
// Plugin
function $gid(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!e) {
        return $();
    }
    if (e.id === id) {
        return $(e);
    }
    // Fallback processing for old IE that matches name attributes
    return $('[id="' + id.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + '"]').filter(function() {
        return this.id === id;
    }).first();
}

// Use
$gid("a$b").css("color", "blue");
$gid("$c").css("color", "green");
```

```html
<div id="a$b">a$b</div>
<div id="$c">$c</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However: If you're going to do it, you have to be careful to tread as softly as possible. That means calling the original with exactly the same number of arguments, the same `this`value, etc.; and making sure that `$.fn.init.prototype` has the same value after you replace `$.fn.init` as before.

Doing both of those things seems to solve the problem:

```js
// Plugin
(function () {
    function escapeJQueryElementName(elementName) {
        elementName = elementName.replace(/\\\$/g, "$");
        return elementName.replace(/\$/g, "\\$");
    }

    var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
    var jQueryInit = $.fn.init;

    $.fn.init = function (arg1) {
        var args = slice.call(arguments, 0);
        if (arg1 && arg1.replace) {
            args[0] = escapeJQueryElementName(arg1);
        }
        return jQueryInit.apply(this, args);
    };
    $.fn.init.prototype = $.fn;
})();

// Use
$("#a$b").css("color", "blue"); // Using special version that handles $ without \\
$("#$c").css("color", "green"); // Using special version that handles $ without \\
$("<div>Checking '#' selector, should get 0: " + $("#").length + "</div>").appendTo(document.body);
```

```html
<div id="a$b">a$b</div>
<div id="$c">$c</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you to draw my attention to possible problems for this technique, i have updated the condition in your code to strict this only to id and classes selectors, this way we will avoid replacing the $ when not necessary:

        if (typeof(arg1) === "string" && arg1.indexOf("$") !== -1 && (arg1.startsWith(".") || arg1.startsWith("#"))) {
            args[0] = escapeJQueryElementName(arg1);
        }

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to attack this problem by overriding something that should really only be used internally, a nicer solution is a function that will create a new alias of jQuery with support for escaping selectors.

Btw, keep in mind that escaping should not be done for things that are HTML, e.g. `$('<span>give me $$$</span>')`, so I've made a crude check for that.

```js
(function(jQuery) {
  jQuery.withSelectorEscaping = function() {
    function escapeJQueryElementName(elementName) {
      elementName = elementName.replace(/\\\$/g, "$");
      return elementName.replace(/\$/g, "\\$");
    }

    return function(selector, context) {
      // avoid doing this for HTML
      if (selector && selector.replace && selector[0] !== '<') {
        selector = escapeJQueryElementName(selector);
      }
      return jQuery(selector, context);
    };
  }
}(jQuery));

// create new alias here
$ = jQuery.withSelectorEscaping();

// use new alias
console.log($('#'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This code snippet adds a new function to `jQuery` itself called `jQuery.withEscaping`; it returns a function which you can then assign to an alias of your choosing, I picked `$` here but you could also do:

```
$foo = jQuery.withSelectorEscaping();
```

It leaves the behaviour of `jQuery` itself alone and only exposes your escaping feature for things that need it.

Comment: Thanks @Jack for the quick response, it works, but it cause other plugins to stop working, like jQuery-migrate.

Comment: @Anas If those plugins properly extend `jQuery` instead of `$` they should work just fine. Could you give an example of what stops working?

Comment: The $.browser.msie, i am using JQuery 1.11.3, and using JQuery-migrate to support this old method.